# How to get CPU utilization timeline data in intel-vtune using command line?

Tags: performance, intel-vtune

My goal is to generate CPU utilization timeline data from the command line in Vtune. Is there any way to do it?

I can collect Vtune data for hotspots using the following command:

`vtune -collect hotspots -result-dir r000hs program`

Using GUI, I can see the CPU utilization timeline as shown in the picture below:

[image: VTune CPU Utilization]

However, I want to plot the data with high resolution and merge it with some other data to put it in a PDF. **Can this data be generated from the command line?**

I found a [few commands](https://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/support/kb/finding-hotspots-in-your-code-with-the-intel-vtune-command-line-interface_506.html) to do it, but none generated this timeline data. For example,

`vtune -report hotspots -r r000hs -report-output output`

only generates the functions with overall runtime.

Comment: I asked the same question at Intel Community, and here is the solution.

https://community.intel.com/t5/Analyzers/Is-there-any-way-to-get-CPU-utilization-timeline-data-in-vtune/m-p/1527843#M23948

Comment: Also, add `-report-output MyReport.csv -format csv -csv-delimiter comma` at the end to generate output into a CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPU utilization timeline data can be obtained using the below command after running the analysis:

```
$ vtune -report timeline -r <result_dir_name> -report-knob column-by=CPUTime -report-knob bin-count=xx
```

The number of bins for the above command can be obtained by changing the bin-count report knob which accepts whole numbers greater than zero:

For example:

```
$ vtune -report timeline -r r000hs -report-knob column-by=CPUTime -report-knob bin-count=20
```

The column-by report knob can accept the following based on the type of analysis performed using Intel® VTune™ Profiler to generate timeline reports:

*[Analysis Type] - [Data Collection Driver]: [Accepted column-by Report Knobs]*

- HPC - SEP: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType, Vectorization
- HPC - VTSS: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType, Vectorization
- Hotspots - UMS: CPUTime, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- Hotspots - HWEBS/Perf: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType, Vectorization
- Hotspots - HWEBS/VTSS: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType, Vectorization
- Threading - UMS: CPUTime, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- Threading - HWEBS/Perf: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- Threading - HWEBS/VTSS: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- System Overview - SEP: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- Micro-architecture Exploration - SEP:  CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType, Vectorization
- IO - SEP: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- Performance Snapshot - EMON: n/a
- Memory Access - SEP: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- Memory Consumption - TPSS: Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- GPU Hotspots - SEP: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- GPU Offload - Perf: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired, Task, TaskTime, TaskType
- GPU Rendering - SEP: CPI, CPUTime, InstructionsRetired

*where **UMS** is user mode sampling, **HWEBS** is hardware event-based sampling and **EMON, Perf, SEP, TPSS,** and **VTSS** are Intel® VTune™ Profiler data collection drivers.*

*Note: Task and TaskType are only valid with ITT API user tasks.*

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Is there any document that summarizes all such commands supported by Vtune?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have a documentation/user guide for this right now. Sorry for the inconvenience caused. We have raised a documentation request and the Intel® VTune™ Profiler team is working on it. Thanks for raising the same.